# I want to calculate the time complexity of EKF for 3D scenarios, but I need to learn how to calculate it. Is there anyone who can help me?

Tags: 3d, time-complexity

I have UPA, and I used the EKF for tracking the user. I want to calculate the time complexity of his scenario, but I need to figure out how.

I know the time complexity of EKF for 2D scenarios is O(N^3), so I expect the time complexity of the 3D scenario to be also O(N^3) because, in this scenario, we have a planar array, and this does not change the order of the complexity. Is my expectation right or not? If not, can anyone explain how I calculate it?